# Android parsing how to get value from this XML

Tags: java, android, xml, json

just a simple question here. How can I get the return value on this kind of xml

```
 Art C. Cauyao<$@FBID@$>501912568<$@ENDFBID@$>Tessa Rose 
Brainard<$@FBID@$>510831686<$@ENDFBID@$>
Dan Gangan<$@FBID@$>513545777<$@ENDFBID@$>
C Jhec DawAko<$@FBID@$>523059320<$@ENDFBID@$>Jeremy
```

Please see that I am getting Facebook name and Facebook ID
Is there any way about that?

**EDIT**

I found out that it is not an xml but rather A JSON (sorry) now my question really is how can I incorporate that returned value?

**EDIT SECOND**
Sir this what I am doing
Parsing it through this

```
static final String URL_FBFRIEND ="Some URL"+ "getFBFriends.php";
```

Now using that I can now parse some data by using my input values. Here is the code

```
        XMLparser parser2 = new XMLparser(); 
    parser2.getXmlFromUrl(URL_FBFRIEND); 

      //HTTP POST
      String url_Getmembermob= URL_FBFRIEND ;
      String xml_getMembermob=null;
      try {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_Getmembermob);

      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4); 
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("...", "...."));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbID", modGen.facebookID ));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accToken", modGen.tokenID));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reqType", "0"));

      Log.i("nameValuePairs", "nameValuePairs=" + nameValuePairs);

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        xml_getMembermob = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        Log.i("xml-return",""+ xml_getMembermob);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

See that I am logging the returned xml **Log.i("xml-return",""+ xml_getMembermob);** And thats the output

Sir Ive altered your code`
    public static List parseUserList(String userData)
    {
        List ret = new ArrayList();

```
    int index = 0;
    while (index < userData.length())
    {
        int startFbTag = userData.indexOf(FB_NAME, index);
        if (index == -1)
        {

            return ret;
        }
        String name = userData.substring(index, startFbTag - index);
        startFbTag += FB_NAME.length(); // Start of the actual data
        int endFbTag = userData.indexOf(FB_ID, startFbTag);
        if (endFbTag == -1)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unterminated start tag");
        }

        fbTagValue = userData.substring(startFbTag, endFbTag - startFbTag);
        Log.i("UserName",fbTagValue);
        //fbId = Long.parseLong(fbTagValue);
        //ret.add(new User(name, fbId));
        index = endFbTag + FB_ID.length();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I am getting an error here ** fbTagValue = userData.substring(startFbTag, endFbTag - startFbTag);**
what seems to be the problem

Comment: I'm not sure that's valid XML at all - is `$@FBID@$` a valid element name in XML? Note that if this is the complete file format, it's definitely *not* valid XML. Please give us more information.

Comment: @JonSkeet That is whats returning on my xml parser

Comment: What do you mean "returning on my xml parser"? You haven't given us nearly enough context. I strongly suspect this isn't really an XML file at all - it's just a file which very slightly resembles XML.

Comment: @JonSkeet I call my friend and found out that the php is just returning the JSON and my task is to add it dynamically on Listview

Comment: Well this isn't JSON, either. Basically it looks like some horrible custom format which will be unpleasant to work with. So you currently have all the data in a single string?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes sir because im just seeing this on my logcat and it is just one line

Comment: Okay, well I've written some sample code... but if you've got any way of asking for the data format to be changed, it would make life simpler. It's really ugly at the moment - and there are plenty of existing ways of representing structured data; there's no excuse for creating yet another one.

Comment: No, this *isn't* JSON. It's basically a made-up format, by the looks of it. Anyway, the code I've provided should parse it correctly - potentially with some tweaks. It would be better if the server generating the text used a well-known format instead of making up its own though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty horrible format. It's not XML. It's not JSON. Assuming you've already got some sort of `User` class, and that all the data is in a single `String`, you could write something like this (completely untested):

```
private static final String FB_START = "<$@FBID@$>";
private static final String FB_END = "<$@ENDFBID@$>";

public static List<User> parseUserList(String userData)
{
    List<User> ret = new ArrayList<User>();

    int index = 0;
    while (index < userData.length())
    {
        int startFbTag = userData.indexOf(FB_START, index);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            // No tags left. You should check whether you've actually got
            // some data left, and potentially throw an exception. It's not
            // clear what your data format does here.
            return ret;
        }
        String name = userData.substring(index, startFbTag - index);
        startFbTag += FB_START.length(); // Start of the actual data
        int endFbTag = userData.indexOf(FB_END, startFbTag);
        if (endFbTag == -1)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unterminated start tag");
        }

        String fbTagValue = userData.substring(startFbTag, endFbTag - startFbTag);
        long fbId = Long.parseLong(fbTagValue);
        ret.add(new User(name, fbId));
        index = endFbTag + FB_END.length();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Sir one question. The User Class that you said, should I create a new class or is that my activity

Comment: @Androyd: It's a new class. A representation of a user is very different from an activity, isn't it?

Comment: sir ims still trying to figure out a way to get this data. Ive even tried to just split the the string but so far nothing works T_T

Comment: @Androyd: The code I've given *does that for you*. Once you've got the `User` class, you should just be able to use the code I've given you.